# View certificate chain in file like "openssl s_client"

Tags: openssl, command, x509, pki, chain

The command `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com` shows me the certificate chain on top like:

```
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/OU=Domain...
  i:/C=SUBINTERMEDIATE
1 s:/C=SUBINTERMEDIATE
  i:/C=INTERMEDIATE
2 s:/C=INTERMEDIATE
  i:/C=ROOT
...
```

Is there any method to view this structure from Certificate-File?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: The source code for `openssl s_client` is in `<openssl src>/apps/s_client.c`.